# Better alternative to reflection than large switch statement using java 8

Tags: java, reflection, java-8

My old code create a FrameBody subclass based on identifier

```
Class<AbstractID3v2FrameBody> c = (Class<AbstractID3v2FrameBody> Class.forName("org.jaudiotagger.tag.id3.framebody.FrameBody" + identifier);
Class<?>[] constructorParameterTypes = {Class.forName("java.nio.ByteBuffer"), Integer.TYPE};
Object[] constructorParameterValues = {byteBuffer, frameSize};
Constructor<AbstractID3v2FrameBody> construct = c.getConstructor(constructorParameterTypes);
frameBody = (construct.newInstance(constructorParameterValues));
```

But profile analysis shows its a bit slow, the alternative to using reflecting is a big switch statement

```
switch(identifier)
{
    case ID3v24Frames.FRAME_ID_AUDIO_ENCRYPTION:

        frameBody = new FrameBodyAENC(byteBuffer, frameSize);
        break;

    case ID3v24Frames.FRAME_ID_ATTACHED_PICTURE:

        frameBody = new FrameBodyAPIC(byteBuffer, frameSize);
        break;

                .......
    }
```

but I have over 100 identifiers, so its seems a bit cumbersome

Is there a more elegant way to do this in Java 8 ?

Comment: Can you turn it into an enum? Then you can just call the `values` method

Comment: @user no I cannot do tnat, does Java 8 let you create a map of ids to classes/methods or aything like that ?

Comment: what you could do is use `MethodHandles.Lookup::findConstructor` and register each of those in a `Map<ID3v24Frames, MethodHandle>`

Comment: @Eugene that looks like I want, can you add as an answer, is that a Java8 thing not familar with it.

Comment: As a side note, there is no need to write this Reflection code in this complicated way. Instead of `Class.forName("java.nio.ByteBuffer")` you can write `java.nio.ByteBuffer.class` (or `ByteBuffer.class` when you have an `import`). Further, you don’t need the manual array creation, `frameBody = Class.forName("org.jaudiotagger.tag.id3.framebody.FrameBody" + identifier) .asSubclass​(AbstractID3v2FrameBody.class) .getConstructor(ByteBuffer.class, int.class) .newInstance(byteBuffer, frameSize);` But the other important question would be: do you really need a distinct class for every header type?

Comment: Eugene's suggestion to make a map of identifiers to constructor's isn't a bad approach, then you just have to dereference the id to find the correct constructor, but it assumes that the constructors are all the same, otherwise you end up with a lot more reflection code trying to use the constructors. In your case, I'd stick with the switch statement -- it's not that bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**:

This can be simplified indeed as Holger suggests:

```
 Map<String, BiFunction<ByteBuffer, Integer, AbstractID3v2FrameBody>> LOOKUP = Map.of(
           FRAME_ID_AUDIO_ENCRYPTION, FrameBodyAENC::new,   
           FRAME_ID_ATTACHED_PICTURE, FrameBodyAPIC::new
 );
```

And then as simple as:

```
LOOKUP.get(ID3v24Frames.FRAME_ID_AUDIO_ENCRYPTION)
      .apply(byteBuffer, frameSize);
```

**PREVIOUS SUGGESTION**

This is just a sample, you will need to adapt it to your classes:

```
private static final Lookup L = MethodHandles.lookup();
private static final MethodHandle CONS;

static {
    try {
        CONS = L.findConstructor(SomeClass.class, MethodType.methodType(void.class, int.class));
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        throw new RuntimeException(t);
    }
}

private static final Map<String, MethodHandle> LOOK_UP = Map.of(
    "SOME_CLASS", CONS
);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        SomeClass sc = (SomeClass) LOOK_UP.get("SOME_CLASS").invokeExact(42);
        System.out.println(sc.getX());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }

}

static class SomeClass {

    private final int x;

    public SomeClass(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you fill the map manually, like `Map.of("SOME_CLASS", CONS, …)`, there is no need to deal with `MethodHandle` or similar lowlevel features. Just use `Map<String, BiFunction<ByteBuffer, Integer,AbstractID3v2FrameBody>> LOOKUP = Map.of(FRAME_ID_AUDIO_ENCRYPTION, FrameBodyAENC::new, FRAME_ID_ATTACHED_PICTURE, FrameBodyAPIC::new, …);`

Comment: The OP asked for an alternative to reflection. I'm wondering how this is in some way, not reflection? :)

Comment: @Holger indeed! I missed the fact that there is a common piece. thank you

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer using these low levels API's is going to be a lot faster than reflection, if used correctly. Besides, some reflective code will fail in some java versions - because they were never supposed to be allowed; unlike proper usage of `MethodHandle` API

Comment: @Eugene but not as fast as the switch statement... Better after the edit though, with a simple map dereference. Though, still assuming that the constructors are all the same. If that isn't the case, or further processing is needed, then the switch is still better.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer it will be most probably on par with the switch statement and I find a `Map` a lot more readable than a switch.

Comment: @Eugene  Yup, I prefer the map too. As long as the assumption re the constructor stands - the more exceptions you have to add, the less desirable the map becomes. I'd say that a pageful of exceptions at most and you'd want to revisit the switch approach. Of course, the OP hasn't mentioned any variance in the constructors, so I'm tilting at windmills at this point :)

Comment: Thx, looks great will try later, @SoftwareEngineer there is no variance in constructors all the same.

Comment: Problem Map.of() requires Java 9, needs to work with Java 8

Comment: Yes, sorry I solved that. However I dont understand the FRAME_ID_AUDIO_ENCRYPTION, FrameBodyAENC::new,    syntax, cant seem to compile it.

Comment: @Eugene okay, the constructor can throw InvalidTagException, I have to add that to the syntax somehow ?

Comment: Ah, it seems you cannot use this method if method throws exception, and the exception is necessary at moment. Maybe your original approach would work but I dont understand how CONS works with multiple classes